# how to fix "invalid keyword argument for this function" in ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm working on `ModelSerializers` their is a non-model field that is **`uploaded_files = serializers.FileField(required=True, source='files')`** in `BlogSerializer`. The `uploaded_files` does not belong to `BlogModel`.

When is try to upload it gives me **`'files' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`** i know `files` is not a field in `BlogModel` but i tried to add a property method `files(self):` in `BlogModel` which did not work either.

models.py

```
class BlogModel(models.Model):

    BLOG_STATUS = (
        ('PUBLISH', 'Publish'),
        ('DRAFT', 'Draft'),
    )

    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blogs')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=BLOG_STATUS)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'blogs'
        verbose_name = 'Blog'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Blogs'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def files(self): #here is the property i added
        return 'do something'
```

serializers.py

```
class BlogFilesSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    updated_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = BlogFilesModel
        fields = ('blog_files_id', 'blog', 'path',
                  'created_at', 'updated_at')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'path': {
                'error_messages': {
                    'blank': 'File is required'
                },
            }
        }


class BlogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    blog_files = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    uploaded_files = serializers.FileField(required=True, source='files')
    blog_created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = BlogModel
        fields = ('blog_id', 'user', 'title', 'content',
                  'status','blog_files', 'blog_created_at',
                  'uploaded_files',
                  )
```

[image: error trace back]

Hope is have explained my problem well.

Thank you.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with those "files" since you don't have any file-field?

Comment: @IvanStarostin after i  create new Blog obj then i'll save files to `BlogFIlesModel` with `blog` as foreign key reference

Comment: Search for "DRF nested writable serializer".

Comment: @IvanStarostin  thank you sir, changing serializer field to `uploaded_files = serializers.FileField(write_only=True)` solved this probloem.  But how can i upload multiple files in `uploaded_files`